# Whats the most common collective hp of any one hero?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there some way to accumulate the data and find, within the range of 400 hp give or take, the average number of hitpoints a champion has? Regardless of their inventory build or perhaps even including that factor? Bonus points for including the per level of exp.

The purpose of this question is to formulate an exact plan to do the required amount of damage to an enemy champion at any given moment to bring your dps to the point of 'usually' killing for sure.

Sure, some heroe's cant burst appropriatly enough, but those that can could really benefit from such a stradegy. You know the 'point' in your build where your effectiveness dps will (usually) allow you to 1v1 a hero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

****Disclaimer: The following is very rough due to the complexity of LOL. Assume an error margin of 20 percent or more.****

**Survivability Estimates:**

base HP roughly 350 + 100/level.

Effective HP is harder because it actually scales exponentially... Lets go with +150/level from 1-6, +200 per level from 7-11, and +250 per level from 12-18. It starts at around 600 and reaches ~5k by end game. +50% for bruisers, +100% for tanks.

This is most accurate for builds using one MR item and up to one other defensive item. Think a mage with RoA and abyssal scepter, a DPS with QSS or Banshee, or a squishier top.

Its rough, but here is where the numbers come from:

Base HP: 375-475 + 80-120 per level

Base Armor: 30+3/lvl

Base MR: 30 + one ~40 mr item

At late game, most builds have 70-120 armor and MR. This is ~40-60 percent damage reduction, so effective health is about double base health at late game. Early game, its only about 50 percent more. Most builds also have about 400 bonus health, from a rylais, a RoA, a banshees, or something like that.

Adding the base health in, we get around 2500 base health and 50 percent damage reduction, leading to around 5k effective health.

Overall, these are still very rough numbers. A single giant belt or other defensive item can increase a champions health by a huge amount in the mid-game. Likewise, armor/mpen items and runes mess everything up.

Edit: improving estimates

---

**Timing attacks**

One important factor to keep in mind for getting kills without position advantage is what I am going to call the timing attack, a la starcraft. The timing attack is attacking right when your champion hits a relative strength. Some examples:

- The moment you finish a 4k item like IE, Deathcap, or TF.
- The levels 6-7/11-12/16-17 as a champion with a standard ult
- The levels just before your opponent hits their next ult (4-5, 9-10, 14-15) as someone with a nonstandard/no ult: Karma, Teemo, Udyr, etc.
- When you are about to level up and have a catalyst
- When your short-CD ult is up but your opponents long-CD is down.

If you have one or more of these factors on your side, you have a good chance of scoring the kill. Try to predict these and act to enhance them, for example, by going back to shop at the moment when you can barely afford IE, to ensure it gives you the biggest advantage.

Comment: can you source this or show your work?

Answer (score 3):

There's a built-in UI feature that may help you.  HP bars are automatically segmented by 100hp increments.  You can count the number of segments on an enemy hero and know his current total within 100hp.  If your goal is to know, at any given moment, if you have enough damage potential to kill the target, then counting the segments in their HP bar is your best bet.

[image]

Note that you'll still need some math / intuition to factor in their resistances (and your penetration), summoner spells (do they have heal or exhaust?), etc.  Also, counting large numbers of segments can be difficult.  In a game scenario I wouldn't count out 11 segments on Malph, I'd just think "lots of hp".  However, if you're thinking of diving / committing, the enemy should be getting low on hp, which can be counted at a glance.  It's much easier to see that Alistar is around 550 hp.  Overall it's a really useful yet not very well known feature.

Comment: thats pretty darn usefull, i knew about more 'bars' equals more hp, but i hadn't noticed that they were in 100hp segments.

Comment: This is a great tip. However, be aware that these bars experience occasional bugs, in which a player appears to have 6-8 bars when they have 2200 life left or something like that. If the bars on your opponent suddenly look wider than before, it could be that bug. The percentage life is displayed accurately, just the wrong number of bars.